# How to I get around "normal" exiting visual mode?

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I'm trying to write a vimscript function that moves the cursor all the way up or all the way down without changing the column. (similar to the way `:set nostartofline` works).

It works, but when I tried to add a mapping for visual mode, it would exit visual mode.

Here is my script:

```
function! StraightDown()
  let line=line('.')
  let end=line('$')
  exe "normal ".eval(end-line)."j"
endfunction

function! StraightUp()
  let line=line('.')
  exe "normal ".eval(line-1)."k"
endfunction

nnoremap <M-j> :<C-u>call StraightDown()<cr>
nnoremap <M-k> :<C-u>call StraightUp()<cr>

xnoremap <M-j> :<C-u>call StraightDown()<cr>
xnoremap <M-k> :<C-u>call StraightUp()<cr>
```

After experimenting with it, it seems like any command executed with `normal ...` will leave visual mode unless it starts with `v`.

One possible workaround I thought of is to add some more logic, and if I call the function in visual mode, add `v` to the normal command. However, this doesn't work if I'm in visual line or visual block mode.

So really, my TL;DR question is how can I do a `normal` command in visual mode without changing modes?

Comment: Why don't you simply set `nostartofline` and use `gg` and `G`?

Comment: @statox Well, 1. is because I like to think of them as two separate commands, and 2. I'm trying to get better at vimscript. I guess it's practice?  I'm fairly new to vimscript.

Comment: Yes `set nostartofline` and `gg` are two separate commands but I don't understand how it is a problem: simply put `set nostartofline` in your vimrc and use `gg` when you need it. Now if you'd like to keep `startofline` for other commands and `nostartofline` only for `gg` you could create a mapping like that `nnoremap gg :set nostartofline<CR>:normal! gg<CR>:set startofline<CR>`. Now I understand you want to get better at vimscript, I'm just suggesting a workaround for your original problem :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two things we need to do:

1. Since you are using a mapping to execute your function, the mapping rightly has to do `:<c-u>` in order to reliably call the function.  But calling a function that way will indeed break us out of visual mode.  So you should restore the last visual selection by putting `normal gv` near the top of your function.

   But since you only want to do that in visual mode, let's do it like this:

   ```
   function! StraightDown()
       ...
   endfunction

   function! StraightDownVisual()
       normal gv
       call StraightDown()
   endfunction

   nnoremap <M-j> :<C-u>call StraightDown()<cr>

   vnoremap <M-j> :<C-u>call StraightDownVisual()<cr>
   ```

   (An alternative single-function approach would be to pass an argument to indicate whether we were in visual mode or not: `call StraightDown(0)` or `call StraightDown(1)`.  Or another approach is [here](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/b7f429a16c042922751c76f56cdf60ea151c65f8/.vim/plugin/move_until_char_changes.vim#L29-L40).)
2. I suspect your `exe "normal ..."` will now work fine, preserving the visual selection.  But if it really does clear it, then don't use `normal` to move the cursor, call a Vim function instead:

   ```
   let target_col = getcurpos()[4]
   call setpos('.', [0, end, target_col])
   ```

   For more info, see:

   ```
   :h setpos(
   :h getcurpos(
   ```

   You could use `[2]` of `getcurpos()` for the current column, but if `[4]` works for you, then that's probably what you really wanted.

   Interestingly, if I press `$` and then ask

   ```
   :echo getcurpos()
   ```

   then the last number displayed is 2147483647.  I think that is Vim's way of telling me the user wants to be on the *final* column, not whatever column they have actually landed on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this still clears visual mode.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ah. Since you are executing your function through a mapping then the visual selection is always cleared, regardless whether you use `normal` or not in your function. So ... your functions should first do `normal gv` to restore the visual selection, and then `call setpos(...)`.  I have updated my answer, HTH!